# PostgreSQL: /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/postgresql/plperl.so: undefined symbol: Perl_save_strlen

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to create **plperl** extension in **PostgreSQL 9.6** (EDB single click executable file)

```
    postgres=# create extension plperl;
    ERROR:  could not load library "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/postgresql/plperl.so": /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/postgresql/plperl.so: undefined symbol: Perl_save_strlen
```

> Perl version I am using.

```
    -bash-4.2$ perl --version
```

> This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for
>   x86_64-linux

I have checked the library file **plperl**.so using the **ldd** but it got executed successfully.

I have searched a lot and not able to find what is **"Perl_save_strlen"** and to which module it belongs in Perl.

Comment: Try with a Perl older than 5.20. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I have tried with 5.16 initially and it was failed to create, so I tried with 5.20 still facing the issue. I am able to create the language in 9.4 version with perl 5.16.